# Running Angular project downloaded from gitlab

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

downloaded project from gitlab. and after installing npm , and using ng serve -o gives me this error(couple of similar error too) .
Backend giving json responce fine.

- Angular CLI: 13.2.5
- Node: 16.15.0
- Package Manager: npm 8.5.5
- win32 x64

````
Error: node_modules/ngx-editor/lib/commands/Heading.d.ts:2:15 - error TS2459: Module '"prosemirror-commands"' declares 'Command' locally, but it is not exported.

2 import { type Command } from 'prosemirror-commands';
                ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/prosemirror-commands/dist/index.d.ts:2:10
    2 import { Command } from 'prosemirror-state';
               ~~~~~~~
    'Command' is declared here.```
````

Comment: Are those really errors or just warnings? What is the project? If it is public, please share the source. If it is private, ask the author.

Comment: can't share the source. I don' know if its error or warning . on browser it just gives me Cannot GET / and nothing.

Answer (score 2):

on package.json file there was this file "ngx-editor": "^12.4.3",
and deleting and isntalling new "ngx-editor": "^13.0.0", fixed the problemm

Answer (score 0):

node_modules/prosemirror-commands/**dist**/index.d.ts

dist folder contain bundle angular file.
try to run npm i and ng serve  in Angular project outside dist folder.